# php ftp upload problem

Tags: php, upload, ftp

I am trying to write a small php function that will upload files to an FTP server and I keep getting the same error but I cannot find any fix by googling the problem, I am hoping you guys can help me here...

The error I get is: Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Unable to build data connection: No route to host in .

The file was created at the FTP server but it is zero bytes.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$file = "test.dat";

$ftp_server="ftp.server.com";
$ftp_user = "myname";
$ftp_pass = "mypass";
$destination_file = "test.dat";


$cid=ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if(!$cid) {
    exit("Could not connect to server: $ftp_server\n");
}

$login_result = ftp_login($cid, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass);
if (!$login_result) {
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user";
    exit;
} else {
echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user";
}

$upload = ftp_put($cid, $destination_file, $file, FTP_BINARY);
if (!$upload) {
    echo "Failed upload for $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file<br>";
    echo "FTP upload has failed!";
} else {
    echo "Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file";
}

ftp_close($cid);
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

I forgot to put FTP in passive mode using:

```
ftp_pasv($cid, true);
```